# CSS: how to make sprite animate in the same place?

Tags: css

I have an animation of pixel art of a cartoon character standing still, but the animation is sliding which makes it look like the character is walking.

Outcome I want is character animating in the same place and not sliding

HTML

```
<nav class = "nav">
      <div class = "nav-item">
      <ul>
        <div class = "agumon">
          <img class = "agumon-standing" src="images/sprites/standing/standing-collection.png" alt="agumon sprite">
        </div>
        <li><a href="#"></a>Home</li>
        <li><a href="#"></a>About Me</li>
        <li><a href="#"></a>Experience</li>
        <li><a href="#"></a>Work</li>
        <li><a href="#"></a>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    
    </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
.agumon{
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(22px * var(--pixel-size));
  height: calc(32px * var(--pixel-size));
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left:41rem;
  display: none;
}

.agumon-standing{
  animation: movespritesheet 2s steps(12) infinite;
  width: calc(320px * var(--pixel-size));
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}

@keyframes movespritesheet {
  from{
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
  }
  to{
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

I have attached the image I am using so you can see how it is animating

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an issue with your sprite. Better define a clear size of each image to get a clear `aspect-ratio`

The below code show the issue with your image and gives you the code that should work fine. The ratio is around `0.77` which produce the bad effect du to rounding. Try to produce a ratio equal to `1`

```css
.box {
  width: 50px; /* control the size here */
  aspect-ratio: 0.77; /* the ratio of on sprite */
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  animation: movespritesheet 2s steps(12) infinite;
}

@keyframes movespritesheet {
  to{transform: translate(-100%)}
}


/* to debug */
.container {
  --s: 50px;

  height:calc(var(--s)/0.77);
  width: calc(12*var(--s));
  outline:2px solid red;
  background: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,#0000 0 calc(var(--s) - 2px),red 0 var(--s)),
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyXSG.png) 0/auto 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>

<div class="box">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyXSG.png" >
</div>
```